# createNamedStoredProcedureQuery can't find @NamedStoredProcedureQuery

Tags: java, jpa

This jpa call of a stored procedure is new to me and I can't seem to call the named stored procedure query that I assigned to an entity. My `Entity` goes like this:

```
import java.util.List;

@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = PolicyEntity.FUNCTION_NAME,
        procedureName = PolicyEntity.PROCEDURE_NAME,
        resultClasses = {PolicyEntity.class},
        parameters = {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type = void.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = List.class)
        })
@Entity
public class PolicyEntity {
    public static final String FUNCTION_NAME = "getPolicyData";
    public static final String PROCEDURE_NAME = "PAP.PAYMENT_HIERARCHY.GET_POLICY_DATA";
    
    @Column(name = "FREZ_CODE")
    private String freezeCode;
    
    @Column(name = "POL_STAT_CD")
    private String polictStatus;
    
    @Column(name = "INS_TYP_BASE")
    private String insuranceType;
    
    @Column(name = "PLAN_CODE_BASE")
    private String planCode;
    
    @Column(name = "VERS_NUM_BASE")
    private String versionNumber;
    
    @Column(name = "CRCY_CODE")
    private String currency;
    
    @Column(name = "LAST_PD_TO_DT")
    private String lptd;
    
    @Column(name = "PD_TO_DT")
    private String ptd;
    
    @Column(name = "POL_NUM")
    private String policyNo;
    
    @Column(name = "REG_TOP_UP")
    private String rtu;
    
    @Column(name = "POL_SUSP")
    private String suppol;
    
    @Column(name = "PMT_SUSP")
    private String suppay;
    
    @Column(name = "DSCNT_PREM")
    private String premium;
    
    @Column(name = "WRK_AREA")
    private String workArea;
    
    @Column(name = "CASH_LOAN_AMOUNT")
    private String cashLoan;
    
    @Column(name = "APL_AMOUNT")
    private String apl;
}
```

The stored procedure it calls expects a list as a `ParameterMode.IN` kind of parameter. While I expect a result set as a return value. However, each time I try to call said `NamedStoredProcedureQuery`, I get the error below:

```
"No @NamedStoredProcedureQuery was found with that name : getPolicyData; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No @NamedStoredProcedureQuery was found with that name : getPolicyData"
```

The implementation that I use to call it goes like this:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class PolicyRepositoryImpl implements PolicyRepository {
    
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    
    @Override
    public String getPolicyData(String policyNo) {
        System.out.println(1);
        StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(PolicyEntity.FUNCTION_NAME);

        System.out.println(2);
        List<String> policyList = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println(3);
        policyList.add(policyNo);

        System.out.println(4);
        query.setParameter("POLICY_LIST", policyList);

        System.out.println(5);
        List<PolicyEntity> policy = query.getResultList();
        
        return null;
    }

}
```

The implementation fails when the `EntityManager` attempts to call the named procedure by using the `createNamedStoredProcedureQuery` method. It seems that it's unable to find the named procedure that I declared. I'm in dire need to understand how to fix this.

I'm not sure if the info I provided is enough but please do ask if I need to provide more.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `procedureName` is the name of procedure which you created in SQL(Mysql,...). And another approach is: in repository extend Interface JpaRepository we could use
@Query(value = "CALL procedureName(:param);", nativeQuery = true)
void executeProcesure(@Param("param") List param);

Comment: Hi, yes I already checked the procedure that I'm trying to call. By the way, its an oracle function within a package. If you can see in the source code of the `@Entity`, I have already included the package name and the function name that I need to call

Comment: @Repository
public interface PolicyRepository extends JpaRepository<PolicyEntity, Id type> {

  @Procedure(name = "PAP.PAYMENT_HIERARCHY.GET_POLICY_DATA")
  List<PolicyEntity> getPeopleData(@Param("POLICY_LIST") List policyList);
}